# how to edit open graph meta description programmatically and in which file

Tags: php, open-graph

there is this site that I'm editing, I wanna know what file to look for while editing og meta desc. Excerpt seems to be empty on the page I want og desc for, still i'm seeing the desc on pasting the url to facebook. where would possibly my previous developer have put that desc.

Answer (score 0):

They're probably somewhere in the header.php file, or wherever the HTML `<head>` section is. Look for

```
<meta property="og:description" content="Something something" />
```

Comment: it has a theme called divi, i checked into both header.php files (of divi & divi child), but there's no 'meta og:descriptino' seems to be there. PS: it also has this plugin called seo yoast..